# Updating WooCommerce product via REST API using PHP CURL

Tags: php, rest, curl, woocommerce

It seems as if $data isn't correct. I can list products and I get the whole product JSON as a response. But the product in WooCommerce doesn't change the price. When I do the same thing via curl command line, the update is working.
Referring to that: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#update-a-product

What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

$url = "https://wooexample.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/455";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
   "Content-Type: application/json",
   "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode ( 'ck_33fbff7b90dcddba9bd4cbedaeda6b2fa3:cs_4156da18fc357b288e42a7e7b75fa6682b' ),
);
// print_r($headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$data = [
    'regular_price' => '24',
    'price' => '24'
];

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print_r(json_decode($resp));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ty this one, I have checked, it's working perfectly for me.

```
<?php

$url = "https://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wc/v3/products/455";

$consumer_key = 'your consumer key put here..';
$consumer_secret = 'your consumer secre put here..';

$headers = array(
    'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode($consumer_key.':'.$consumer_secret )
);
$data = array(
    'regular_price' => '24',
    'price' => '24'
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$consumer_key:$consumer_secret");
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
curl_close($curl);
print_r(json_decode($resp));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies on the data format you are sending.

the docs is using a library that's supposedly transform the data already in a supported format, while your curl request is posting raw array data via curl

you can try transforming your data into a form data with `http_build_query`

`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data) );`

or convert them into JSON format

`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data) );`

**EDIT**

You also appear to have wrong curl request, you're passing the keys on as base64_encoded authorization in headers, but based on the docs you're supposed to do

```
curl -X PUT https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/794 \
    -u consumer_key:consumer_secret \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{
  "regular_price": "24.54"
}'
```

Your php curl request should have be something like

```
$headers = [
    "Content-Type: application/json",
]
.
.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "your_key_here" . ":" . "your_secret_here");
```

Comment: Yes, it must be about the $data structure. If I add either `json_encode` or `http_build_query`, I receive a `400 Bad Request` as response.

Comment: @Chris I've edited my answer, you are doing wrong request based on the docs

Comment: oh, and you're supposed to post the data as json format, not form data, so you need to use ```json_encode```